# location.hash without page scrolling

Tags: javascript, hash

I have used window.location.hash to jump from a link on a page to a div on another page. This works well. However, when the new page opens, it shows first the top of the page and scrolls then down to the div. The code I used for this is given below.

Question: how can I change the code so that the new page is loaded at the div immediately, without scrolling (or jumping) from the top of the page to the div?

```
  if (window.location.hash) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('html, body').scrollTop(0).show();
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top
                }, 1000)
        }, 0);
    }
    else {
        $('html, body').show();
    }
```

Comment: Have you written that code yourself? Then you should know what scrollTop and animate achieve here, right?

Comment: Simply remove the code...

Comment: It sounds like you just want the default behavior of an anchor link used to jump to a specific element on a different page. If so, the solution would be to remove this script, which has the one purpose of interfering with said default behavior only ...

Comment: I didn't write the code myself.

Answer (score 0):

I do it in this way because their is a timeout on the page during loading. When I do it in the normal way, thus without this code, it doesn't work because of the timeout. Any suggestions?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myVar;
function loadpage() {
myVar = setTimeout(showPage, 500);
}

function showPage() {
  document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "block";
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')
  map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(50.849348, 4.7356652))
  if (window.location.hash) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('html, body').scrollTop(0).show();
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top
                }, 0)
        }, 0);
    }
    else {
        $('html, body').show();
    }
}
</script>
```